# Restore Package angular 2

Tags: angular, model-view-controller

I am trying to learn angular 2. I am trying to perform "Restore Packages" on package.jason. In the training there was no issue when the trainer in the video performed this action with no issue.

I am using visual studio 2015.

In the output I get the following errors:

```
====Executing command 'npm install'====

npm WARN package.json angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No README data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/reflect-metadata
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/systemjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lite-server
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/concurrently
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-htmlfile-reporter
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-server
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/canonical-path
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-chrome-launcher
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/typings
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-core
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tslint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular2-in-memory-web-api
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/common
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/forms
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/http
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/router
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/router-deprecated
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/upgrade
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/reflect-metadata
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/systemjs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lite-server
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-server
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/concurrently
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-htmlfile-reporter
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/canonical-path
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-chrome-launcher
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/typings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-core
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tslint
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular2-in-memory-web-api
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/common
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/forms
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/http
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'angular/common' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'angular2-quickstart'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\\\node\\node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd c:\users\nojha\documents\visual studio     2015\Projects\Angular2TestApplication\Angular2TestApplication
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code E404
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/router
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/router-deprecated
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/upgrade
npm

====npm command completed with exit code 1====
```

How do I fix it ?

Comment: Looks like `angular2-quickstart` is obsolete and no longer being maintained, maybe you got the package name wrong. Also there is an error with `@angular/common`, its  missing an **@**. But just to be sure you should also include the `package.json` file in your question.

Comment: I have package.json . I will check @angular/common. thanks